# reception of radio waves with an android phone

Tags: android, fm-radio

Good evening everybody,
I would like to develop an application under android, which can receive frequencies from a radio stations.
My idea is to scan the radio frequencies between two values. ie, "scan" between a minimum frequency and maximum frequency.
eg: a button starts the scan from (87.5 MHz - 108 MHz) => (87.5 MHz <= f = <108 MHz).
But so far I do not know where to start! I have lots of questions in my head.
- How do we know that such an android terminal has a radio receiver? Ie is there a function or activity system can help us to detect its presence?
- What I need for this type of development?

Comment: I'm confused -- are you looking to develop an FM radio app for phones that don't have FM radios?

Comment: I am looking for a way to return control. for example: all scannig radio station between 87.5 MHz and 108 MHz. or to manually enter the frequency

Comment: the phone has an FM radio receiver option but i looking to develop an other one (personalized radio Application)

Answer (score 4):

There is no FM Radio API in android. Any FM Radios on phones are firmware unique to each phone.

Comment: thx foryour response, how to interact with firmware?

Comment: im just a begginer.   thank you